# Is A.L.I.E written in JavaScript?

Tags: the-100

In the 3rd season, 14th episode there are shown parts of A.L.I.E codes including something very similar to JavaScript. Did Becca write A.L.I.E in JavaScript?

screen shot: [image]

Comment: Maybe a screenshot can help us, so even those who did not watch it, or did not mind reading it at he time can answer

Comment: The wiki article suggests that it might be JULIA, a sort of weird language used for high speed nunerical analysis. It's been seen elsewhere in the show, apparently.

Comment: Not in the least bit opinion-based. Either it is or it isn't.

Comment: not enough information in the given screenshot - would need to see quite a bit more. From what is shown, it *appears* to be an object-oriented language but that doesn't make it javascript or even a real language

Comment: 'array.prototype' is javascript but that doesn't mean the code shown is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In universe, A.L.I.E is coded in JULIA.**

[image]

You can see this same function [here in GitHub](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/97f80c3dd05fb54db1b737db809149636ae0c25a/base/abstractarraymath.jl#L179) (without the interestingly placed line breaks)

```
function repmat(a::AbstractVecOrMat, m::Int, n::Int=1)
    o, p = size(a,1), size(a,2)
    b = similar(a, o*m, p*n)
    for j=1:n
```

**Out of universe, you have random nonsense on the screen.**

[image]

```
iage.tx473|||^^|| sqrl.an
ox.mp935((0))HM.loop.fn")
_ttl - fp->lp_ttl;    (ip
n*l)[]#ifdef _KERNEL inet
fn*|)[_#

array.prototype.access
```

The background looks almost like C, but don't quote me on that. And the foreground is pseudo JavaScript (`access` is not a real function of [`array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)).